# Vertical lines not passing through all cells

Tags: tables, multicol, multirow

I'm attempting to recreate this table in Latex:

[image]

My code so far is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|cc|cc|cc|cc}
     & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8}\\\hline
    \textbf{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{8}{*}{a}} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{b}} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{d}} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{f}}\\
    \textbf{B} & & & & & & &\\
    \textbf{C} & & & & & & &\\
    \textbf{D} & & & & & & &\\\cline{4-9}
    \textbf{E} & & &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{c}} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{e}} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{g}}\\
    \textbf{F} & & & & & & &\\
    \textbf{G} & & & & & & &\\
    \textbf{H} & & & & & & &\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The output of which is:

[image]

However, the vertical lines break 2nd and 6th rows, which I cannot fix.

How do I make the vertical lines pass through all the cells?

Comment: Change `c` to `|c|` in your `\multicolumn`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a single `|` to the relevant \multicolumn preambles:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|cc|cc|cc|cc}
     & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} & \textbf{5} & \textbf{6} & \textbf{7} & \textbf{8}\\\hline
    \textbf{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{8}{*}{a}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{b}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{d}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{f}}\\
    \textbf{B} & & & & & & &\\
    \textbf{C} & & & & & & &\\
    \textbf{D} & & & & & & &\\\cline{4-9}
    \textbf{E} & & &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{c}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{e}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{g}}\\
    \textbf{F} & & & & & & &\\
    \textbf{G} & & & & & & &\\
    \textbf{H} & & & & & & &\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that table easily with `niceamtrix` (≥ 5.19 of 2021-07-23).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}c|cc|cc|cc|cc}
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ \Hline
A & \Block{*-2}{a}  &   & \Block{3-2}{b} & & \Block{3-2}{d} & & \Block{3-2}{f} \\
B \\
C \\
D \\ \cline{4-9}
E & & & \Block{3-2}{c} & & \Block{3-2}{e} & & \Block{3-2}{g} \\
F \\
G \\
H
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]